# error: terminating connection due to administrator command on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a nodejs application in a container, but after a certain time the application breaks with the following error:

```
node:events:496
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

error: terminating connection due to administrator command
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/servidor/nodetest/node_modules/pg-protocol                                                                                                                                                             /dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/servidor/nodetest/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist                                                                                                                                                             /parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/home/servidor/nodetest/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser                                                                                                                                                             .js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/servidor/nodetest/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/                                                                                                                                                             index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at Client._handleErrorEvent (/home/servidor/nodetest/node_modules/pg/lib/clie                                                                                                                                                             nt.js:341:10)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (/home/servidor/nodetest/node_modules/pg/lib/cl                                                                                                                                                             ient.js:352:12)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at /home/servidor/nodetest/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:12
    at Parser.parse (/home/servidor/nodetest/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser                                                                                                                                                             .js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/servidor/nodetest/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/                                                                                                                                                             index.js:11:42)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5) {
  length: 116,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '57P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'postgres.c',
  line: '3109',
  routine: 'ProcessInterrupts'
}

Node.js v20.11.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I thought it could be something with the connection to the bank, but my application only connects to the bank after entering the update route, like in this example:

```
app.put('/update', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        let body = req.body


        const client = await connect();
        
        // Checking if the import exists
        let queryResult = await client.query(`SELECT pallet_no FROM public.import_result_all WHERE pallet_no = '${body.pallet_no}' LIMIT 1`);
        if (queryResult?.rows?.length <= 0) {
            return res.status(400).json({message: "This import does not exist"});
        }


    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).json({error: true, message: "An internal error occurred"})
    } finally {
        await disconnect();
    }
})
```

It executes the connection function, executes the query, and then at `finally` it disconnects from the db.